# iTunes connect override accidentally

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

Our company has Company iOS Dev Account.

Last Friday, 25/9/2015, we registered Company iOS Dev Account Apple ID as internal tester in client iOS Dev Account. First time, itunes connect showed error message that registered email(Company Apple ID) already have iTunes connect account. But when we tried second time, it passed validation and registered as internal tester in client iOS Dev Account. After a while, we realised our company apps in iTunes Account were gone and only left as tester of client app. So, we removed our company account as tester in client itunes connect. But it didn't solve, now all apps're gone.

We contacted Apple Tech Support Team Mail. But no reply yet until now.
May I know how can I solve this situation ?
Shall I use DTS to report that ? Will it be fast ?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, we got help from Apple and can login and see as original itunes connect when we login with secondary email as instructed by Apple. Soon, apple made it to login with primary apple id as original.

Thanks

Comment: same thing happened with us, our legal/admin account is added is given a Technical Role and now we cannot add other users, any idea what should be done ?

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi your iTunes connect account is added as Technical Role in other iTunes connect account ?

Comment: No, in the same ItunesConnect account,

Comment: on which mail address you did contact to apple ? i have submitted my query through the iTunesConnect Contact Us System

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi I think it take transaction time. We got reply from asia.dev@asia.apple.com

Comment: How much time it took for you ?

Comment: We did that on Friday. Saturday, we realized our account all app has cleared. Then we reported. On Monday, we got mail reply

Comment: thanks for your kind responses, we have recovered our Account, :)